# LInkedIn oAuth2 request token 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I am fighting second day with LinkedIN API , each time I am trying to get a token , I am getting 400 Bad Request.

Here is my code , maybe someone can help with this ?

```
public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, System.Uri returnUrl)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code" +
                 "&client_id={0}" +
                 "&scope={1}" +
                 "&state={3}" +
                 "&redirect_uri={2}",this._consumerKey,_scope,HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()),Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    context.Response.Redirect(url);
}

public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
{
    //TODO: check CSRF
    string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

    string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
    //From this we need to remove code portion
    rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

    string authUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
    string postData = String.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}", code,HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]), _consumerKey, _consumerSecret);

    //WebClient client = new WebClient();
    //var getReq =  client.DownloadString(authUrl + "?" + postData);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(authUrl + "?" + postData) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    //This "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; line is important
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
    requestWriter.Close();

    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
}
```

Any thought ? Maybe someone solved similar in past ?

Comment: A wrong date in your machine might be the cause for the 400 error. (A bit late for you but might helpful to someone)

Comment: Did you found the answer? can you post it here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same **redirect_uri** in both

```
public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, System.Uri returnUrl)
```

And

```
public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
```

function. But in your code **redirect_uri** of first function  **HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())** and second function **HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])** are not same (I think). So make sure you have fix this problem. You code may be worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged this, here's some of the things I tried before it was successful. I'm not sure which one made it correct, so I'll put them all down just in case you need somewhere to start:

- HTTP protocol 1.1
- Add a `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header
- Do not refresh the response from the authorization code return page; the code in the URL parameter (`$_GET['code']` in PHP) apparently can't be re-used ([another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723227/linkedin-api-access-token-generation-error) says it expires every 20 seconds)

  - To put it another way, don't try to re-use or cache the authorization code, flow it directly into the access token request ASAP
- Do try to use another application (like SoapUI or Fiddlr) to hit the endpoint to show it is working, and to see some headers more clearly

  - That being said, looking at the response headers (not just the response code) can be helpful
- Sending the data as POST content not as a URL parameter

Note that a `400` error indicates a malformed request ([400 BAD request HTTP error code meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)) not a missing resource (`404`) which can also be a gotcha if you're thinking too fast.

Comment: As you have mentioned, i tried all, but still i'm not able to get access token, as my redirect URL is also correct. can you help me to fix this.sharing my code post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501144/unable-to-get-access-token-linkedin-oauth`