# 400 BAD request HTTP error code meaning?

Tags: rest, http, error-handling, http-status-code-400

I have a JSON request which I'm posting to a HTTP URL.

Should this be treated as `400` where `requestedResource` field exists but `"Roman"` is an invalid value for this field?

```
[{requestedResource:"Roman"}]
```

Should this be treated as `400` where `"blah"` field doesn't exist at all?

```
[{blah:"Roman"}]
```

Comment: Maybe [402](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.3), if they really want to be able to send the value `Roman`, they just need to pay you more :)

Comment: A real scenario where I saw this - I did a PUT call to add some data. I did a put call again using the same request body and got a 400 which told me that a previous request is being already processed. Its normal for our system to take some time to add that data.

Comment: I'm sure most noticed, but to mention explicitly - these requests should be 400 responses, because they are not valid JSON (not the main point of the question I know!)
JSON requires quotes around Property names, and is not forgiving like javascript object notation that does not require the quotes. My answer to primary question is below.

Answer (score 395):

A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, 400's are typically, and correctly I would say, used to indicate that the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the service.

By that logic, both the scenarios you provided should be 400s.

Imagine instead this were XML rather than JSON. In both cases, the XML would never pass schema validation--either because of an undefined element or an improper element value. That would be a bad request. Same deal here.

Comment: I agree with you up to "By that logic, both the scenarios you provided should be 400's." I don't think content of the JSON should matter here. When you say malformed I would like to believe that addresses the issues in the format of the data you send, for example if you skip a field in the JSON you should get 400.

Comment: There is a decent set of REST response codes at http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html. It may also depend on how you want to handle a valid  request such as a 406 (Not Acceptable) or 405 method not allowed. However, 400 is appropriate because "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

Comment: So *"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax"* can be either of the **request** (for example, one of the HTTP headers being malformed) or the **data** carried by the request (for example, a JSON value missing)?

Comment: Vidya says "the XML would never pass schema validation". Point being that XML parsers distinguish between a document being well-formed (i.e. syntactically sound) and valid (i.e. semantically sound, e.g. according to a schema). The description of the 400 code is "the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed *syntax*" - so it shouldn't be used for validation errors, imho.

Comment: @Vidya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851301/get-http-400-bad-request-ionic-2 take a look at this error i am also facing same issue similar to this error if you know please help me

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, if you get a 400 and you are not explicitly returning that from your controller's action method, then is it safe to say that the action method did not even get a chance to execute?

Answer (score 85):

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Comment: The correctness of returning an error 400 isn't based on a field vs a value but the request as a whole.  I think HTTP 400 is a good way to go

Comment: Do you mean that a 400 response be used to tell clients that anything, i.e. url, headers, body etc., in the request could be wrong and not just the body ?

Comment: well for url the correct code is 404, for headers, I guess it's a toss up, 403 (forbidden) seems like the right way to go if headers are rejecting identity, but what if headers are determining output format? about the only path I think feels right for 400 is in the situation where an action is being requested that does not make sense and should not be repeated.  I wrote this answer 4 years ago, these days I feel like even errors should return 200, and that errors should only apply to the http transmission and not the payload.

Comment: This answer covers a lot of this, though I haven't read through all of the charts yet https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324179/16959

Comment: @JasonSperske load balancers, proxies and other middleware often use status codes to help route, report & repair.  fortunately codes like "422" are expressly regarding the payload, so there is some room in the spec for payload status codes.

Answer (score 58):

Selecting a HTTP response code is quite an easy task and can be described by simple rules. The only tricky part which is often forgotten is paragraph 6.5 from RFC 7231:

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a
>   representation containing an explanation of the error situation,
>   and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Rules are as following:

1. If request was successful, then return 2xx code (3xx for redirect). If there was an internal logic error on a server, then return 5xx. If there is anything wrong in client request, then return 4xx code.
2. Look through available response code from selected category. If one of them has a name which matches well to your situation, you can use it. Otherwise just fallback to x00 code (200, 400, 500). If you doubt, fallback to x00 code.
3. Return error description in response body. For 4xx codes it must contain enough information for client developer to understand the reason and fix the client. For 5xx because of security reasons no details must be revealed.
4. If client needs to distinguish different errors and have different reaction depending on it, define a machine readable and extendible error format and use it everywhere in your API. It is good practice to make that from very beginning.
5. Keep in mind that client developer may do strange things and try to parse strings which you return as human readable description. And by changing the strings you will break such badly written clients. So always provide machine readable description and try to avoid reporting additional information in text.

So in your case I'd returned 400 error and something like this if "Roman" is obtained from user input and client must have specific reaction:

```
{
    "error_type" : "unsupported_resource",
    "error_description" : "\"Roman\" is not supported"
}
```

or a more generic error, if such situation is a bad logic error in a client and is not expected, unless developer made something wrong:

```
{
    "error_type" : "malformed_json",
    "error_description" : "\"Roman\" is not supported for \"requestedResource\" field"
}
```

Answer (score 24):

In neither case is the "syntax malformed". It's the semantics that are wrong. Hence, IMHO a 400 is inappropriate. Instead, it would be appropriate to return a 200 along with some kind of error object such as `{ "error": { "message": "Unknown request keyword" } }` or whatever.

Consider the client processing path(s). An error in syntax (e.g. invalid JSON) is an error in the logic of the program, in other words a bug of some sort, and should be handled accordingly, in a way similar to a 403, say; in other words, something bad has gone wrong.

An error in a parameter value, on the other hand, is an error of semantics, perhaps due to say poorly validated user input. It is not an HTTP error (although I suppose it could be a 422). The processing path would be different.

For instance, in jQuery, I would prefer not to have to write a single error handler that deals with both things like 500 and some app-specific semantic error. Other frameworks, Ember for one, also treat HTTP errors like 400s and 500s identically as big fat failures, requiring the programmer to detect what's going on and branch depending on whether it's a "real" error or not.

Comment: +1, The **P** in HTTP stands for **Protocol** and if the response is an HTTP error, it should be a low-level problem.  I’ve avoided a lot of code complexity over the years using the approach described by torazaburo.  There would be less pain in REST land if we all wrote *resilient* code instead of so frequently blowing up with HTTP errors.

Comment: 200 means that request has been processed, so a normal success logic should be executed on a client. Here we definitely have an error, so response can't have 2xx or 3xx code. It can't be 5xx either because that's a server side error and we have an error on client side. So that must be an 4xx error. But the error description in response body is a right thing to do and is actually a way advised by HTTP specification.

Comment: 422 is better, for loggers, proxies and other tools

Comment: i know this is old but for information's sake, it's an invalid request to that particular server a good status code to use for that is 422 it's a client error as it's HTTP syntactically correct, but the request is unprocessable because it's not semantically for that request on that server, and while that status code was made for WebDAV it's purpose is the same thing and should be valid in this use  you can see a full list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes,

Answer (score 19):

Using `400` status codes for any other purpose than indicating that the *request* is malformed is just plain wrong.

If the request payload contains a byte-sequence that could not be parsed as `application/json` (if the server expects that dataformat), the appropriate status code is `415`:

> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of
>   the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for
>   the requested method.

If the request payload is syntactically correct but semantically incorrect, the non-standard `422` response code may be used, or the standard `403` status code:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

Comment: no, 415 is for when the entity is claimed to be of the wrong type eg `image/gif` instead of `text/json`  in the  `Content-Type:` header.  - presumably this is also applicable if a component of a multipart has the wrong type specified, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918 where it discusses 422 for more discussion,

Answer (score 10):

Think about expectations.

As a client app, you expect to know if something goes wrong on the server side. If the server needs to throw an error when `blah` is missing or the `requestedResource` value is incorrect than a 400 error would be appropriate.

Comment: My sentiments exactly.

Answer (score 9):

This reminds me of a common dialog with others, "I understand - I just don't Agree"

400 means the server didn't understand

200 means the server understood exactly and fully processed the request.

When a server returns 200 it is saying, "I understood what you are asking for, I processed it without unexpected errors, and here is my proper response"

200 means you can trust the answer sent in the response.  Maybe the answer is "Romans aren't allowed" - but still, it is a proper answer, generated without any *unexpected* problems.

200 doesn't express any information about Expected errors or Handled Exceptions - because that is not part of the Message Transport process. These are status codes about HTTP, the Status of the Transport itself.

I believe Blurring the line between "Transport/Communication" VS "Processing" should be avoided.

For those who prefer HTTP Codes to indicate problem in processing (the "I don't agree" part) it seems 409 Conflict is the most applicable to "Romans not allowed"
[RFC 7231 409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-60)

Conflict pretty much means "lack of agreement" right?

No matter what you choose for HTTP response code, it seems everyone agrees your response should explain Why it failed, and what to do to resolve it.  In the case of Roman, maybe return a list of acceptable values for the field?

Answer (score 7):

First check the URL it might be wrong, if it is correct then check the request body which you are sending, the possible cause is request that you are sending is missing right syntax.

To elaborate , check for special characters in the request string. If it is (special char) being used this is the root cause of this error.

try copying the request and analyze each and every tags data.

Comment: I was getting http 400 error, I checked my request had some special characters. To fix that, I passed the charset=UTF-8 in the content type.

Answer (score 6):

As a complementary, for those who might meet the same issue as mine, I'm using `$.ajax` to post form data to server and I also got the `400` error at first.

Assume I have a javascript variable,

```
var formData = {
    "name":"Gearon",
    "hobby":"Be different"
    };
```

Do not use variable `formData` directly as the value of key `data` like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/user/add",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); 
    }
});
```

Instead, use JSON.stringify to encapsulate the `formData` as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/user/add",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); 
    }
});
```

Anyway, as others have illustrated, the error is because the server could not recognize the request cause malformed syntax, I'm just raising a instance at practice. Hope it would be helpful to someone.

Comment: I think OP is asking if 400 is the appropriate error-code to _return_, when the request is not malformed, but somehow does not meet application-level requirements. E.g. you could create an online calculator, where you send equations as JSON. If you send valid json of adding a number with a string, then the request is correct, but semantically incorrect to the application. Your browser will however see the request as 'bad'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it meant that the data I was providing in json was not compatibile with required data for db, for example email address was already added into db and then it throws code 400