# Setting a HTTP response code in PHP (under Apache)

Tags: php, apache

Given the following two methods for setting a HTTP response code in PHP (specifically, under Apache):

**Method 1:**

```
http_response_code(404);
```

**Method 2:**

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

My questions are:

1. Aside from the fact that `http_response_code` is only available in PHP 5.4 or greater, what are the differences between the two approaches and why/when to use one over the other?
2. Where does the [Reason Phrase](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) come from when using the first example? (I've checked and a Reason Phrase *is* generated from somewhere)

Comment: Good question. Wondering why it was so heavily down-voted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I'm being downvoted into oblivion for no apparent reason, I've managed to answer this myself by scouring through the PHP source code.  Hopefully this serves as a reference for anyone else trying to work this out.

The two methods are essentially functionally equivalent. `http_response_code` is basically a shorthand way of writing a http status header, with the added bonus that PHP will work out a suitable [Reason Phrase](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) to provide by matching your response code to one of the values in an enumeration it maintains within [php-src/main/http_status_codes.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/http_status_codes.h).

Note that this means your response code must match a response code that PHP knows about. You can't create your own response codes using this method, however you can using the `header` method. Note also that `http_response_code` is only available in PHP 5.4.0 and higher.

**In summary - The differences between `http_response_code` and `header` for setting response codes:**

1. Using `http_response_code` will cause PHP to match and apply a Reason Phrase from a list of Reason Phrases that are hard-coded into the PHP source code.
2. Because of point 1 above, if you use `http_response_code` you must set a code that PHP knows about. You can't set your own custom code, however you can set a custom code (and Reason Phrase) if you use the `header` function.
3. `http_response_code` is only available in PHP 5.4.0 and higher