# Error 400 Bad request when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small and likely silly oversight on a piece of script that was actually working a few weeks ago.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#subscribe-btn" ).click(function() {
        var email = $( "#subscribe-input" ).val();
        if(email != ""){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/subscribers",
                data: {
                  email : email
                },
                dataType: "html"
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Email field is empty!");
        };
    });
});
```

When the button is clicked, it returns the error `400 (Bad Request)`. How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you looked in the server logs? What are you seeing there? Is there a stack trace you can share?

Comment: @AlexLynham, your spot on!

Comment: Possibly a bad contentType. By default, $.ajax() uses `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`. Perhaps you need to use something else? `contentType: application/json`?

Comment: [This SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Improved the title to better reflect your question. As @AlexLynham mentions please add more details like stack trace or server logs. Add any changes that were made after which the code started giving the error.

Comment: Without understanding what data the server-side script is expecting, it is impossible to tell you why the AJAX call would return 400 error.

Comment: what is /subscribers? That doesn't look valid.

Comment: @jordaniac89, its fine. its a url from the application