# No JSON object gets passed when using $.ajax() function call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I wrote this piece of code in order to catch the user input data from a HTML table, and then using ajax to pass it to the back end. Note before the `$.ajax()` function call in the following code, I was able to see the output from the console, this means any code before line 15 is working properly.
The screen shot is the output from code line 15:
[image]

```
$('form').submit(                                                            //line 1
            function(e) {                                                    //line 2
                e.preventDefault();                                          //line 3
                var header = $('table thead tr th').map(function() {         //line 4
                return $(this).text();                                       //line 5
                });                                                          //line 6

                var tableObj = $('table tbody tr').map(function(i) {         //line 7
                var row = {};                                                //line 8
                $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {                        //line 9
                    var rowName = header[i];                                 //line 10
                    row[rowName] = $(this).find("input").val();              //line 11
                });                                                          //line 12
                    return row;                                              //line 13
                }).get();                                                    //line 14
                console.log(tableObj);                                       //line 15

                $.ajax({
                 url:"/spring-mvc-webapp/jsondata",
                 type:'POST',
                 data :JSON.stringify(tableObj),
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 success:function(result){console.log(result);},
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                }
                });//end ajax
            }
        );
```

I got this error message from the alter box:

> jqXHR: 200
>
> textStatus: parsererror
>
> errorThrown: SyntaxError:  unexpected end of input

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="/spring-mvc-webapp/jsondata" method="post">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gross Weight</th>
                    <th>Tare Weight</th>
                    <th>Price Per Pound</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

I did not include back-end java code because I already know that the `$.ajax()` is not working properly, if you think it is necessary, I will add the back-end code.

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Why no `JSON` data gets posted through `$.ajax()`?

Comment: can you show line 15 output, i mean console.log on line15

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan i attached the screen shot, please have a look

Comment: I tried your code without passing any values in the textbox and it worked fine. I am guessing the problem could be the action url. Does it exist? Can you verify that?

Comment: try   dataType: "jsonp",          instead of  dataType: "json", and let me know ok

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan tried. still not working..

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh yes. the url is valid. It is the matching url for my back-end controller.

Comment: One observation is, you have both form action and ajax url in your code. Can you replace input type="submit" with just a normal button and handle the click event instead?

Comment: It's a server-side error most likely or the request is not hitting the right URL. Check on the network tab of your browser.

Comment: @MinusFour I updated the error message to the OP, please advise.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I updated the OP, and the error message is shown in my alter box, please see my updated post and advise.

Comment: JSON should be passed as-is into your `data` parameter, there is no need to stringify it.

Comment: @Terry I tried to pass it directly but got the 400 error.

Comment: 400 means malformed syntax. If you are sure that the JSON you are sending to the URL is valid, have you checked what is the format of the data the script (at the recipient URL) expects? If it is not set up to parse JSON but something else, it will of course throw a parse error: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning

Answer (score 0):

You should send your data directly as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/spring-mvc-webapp/jsondata",
    type:'POST',
    data :tableObj,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success:function(result){console.log(result);},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});//end ajax
```

Or send a JSON containing your serialized data:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/spring-mvc-webapp/jsondata",
    type:'POST',
    data : { data: JSON.stringify(tableObj) },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success:function(result){console.log(result);},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});//end ajax
```