# 400 whitepage label error when using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Hello i'm getting a 400 bad request when trying to access an endpoint. Im using spring mvc and mapped my url to my page but failing to access the endpoint when using `window.location.href`. Please what did i do wrong

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'guest/search',

            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(dataRecieved){
                var dataRecieved= $.trim(dataRecieved);
                //console.log(dataRecieved);
                if(dataRecieved === 'true'){
                    $("#statusPlaceholder").html("Great rooms are available");
                    window.location.href="/guestReservation"; //fails to go to the endpoint
                }else{
                    $("#statusPlaceholder").html("Sorry. Rooms are not available. Please try again").show().fadeOut(3000).css("color","red");
                }
            }

        });
```

My mapped endPoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guestReservation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String createGuest(@RequestBody Occupancy occupancy){
        return "guestReservation";
    }
```

This is my Occupancy class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Occupancy")
public class Occupancy implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 15L;

    public Occupancy() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="OCCUPANCYID", nullable = false)
    private long occupancyID;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="itinaryID")
    private Itinary itinary;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roomNumber", referencedColumnName = "roomID")
    private Room room;

    @Column(name="roomsWanted")
    private int roomsWanted;

    public int getRoomsWanted() {
        return roomsWanted;
    }

    public void setRoomsWanted(int roomsWanted) {
        this.roomsWanted = roomsWanted;
    }

    //    @Column(name="status", columnDefinition = "default 0")
    private int status; // 0:reserved 1:cheched-in 2:checked-out

    private Date checkInDate;
    private Date checkOutDate;


    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getOccupancyID() {
        return occupancyID;
    }

    public Itinary getItinary() {
        return itinary;
    }

    public void setItinary(Itinary itinary) {
        this.itinary = itinary;
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

//    public int getNunOfPerson() {
//        return NunOfPerson;
//    }
//
//    public void setNunOfPerson(int nunOfPerson) {
//        NunOfPerson = nunOfPerson;
//    }

    public Date getCheckInDate() {
        return checkInDate;
    }

    public void setCheckInDate(Date checkInDate) {
        this.checkInDate = checkInDate;
    }

    public Date getCheckOutDate() {
        return checkOutDate;
    }

    public void setCheckOutDate(Date checkOutDate) {
        this.checkOutDate = checkOutDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you directly access the full url in the browser (eg:-  `http://www.something.com/guestReservation`)

Comment: @Abhi you are right was actually trying that before  mentioned it. Actually i could not access it

Comment: These links may help [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19671511/2968762) [Link 2](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/browsers/fl/http-400-bad-request.htm). Try checking logs for debugging. I guess you are missing some parameters.

Comment: try this ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/guestReservation and please give me to response what should be output is occuer.

Comment: @sanjay i tried what u said and now i get a 404 error

Comment: In your web.xml file how to give <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> same like or different please give me your url-pattern

Comment: @sanjay im doing it in spring boot. When i remove the request body it seems to be no issue but now when i have the request body in it having problems

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because of parameters expected in the /guestReservation API call.

I see in the method definition, the parameter is of type **Guest**. You need to check what is that you are expecting in this class.

Adding the required parameters should fix your issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: how can i add the required parameter. You are right its causing an issue

Comment: Check the *Guest* Class. If possible paste the contents of this class in the question to help you further.

Comment: actually its occupancy class. I am trying to reach an endpoint and post data from a from. The model is an occupancy class

Comment: so i am originally sending a json response from spring either a true or false. When true i want to redirect me to the url /guestReservation. Occupation is just receiving a post from the url /guestReservation

Comment: You are explaining about /guest/search. I am asking about /guestReservation. In your method definition, you wrote **createGuest(@RequestBody Occupancy occupancy)** which means the GET request should have the payload JSON as mentioned in Occupancy class. If not you will receive 400.

Comment: i have added the occupancy class