# Android HttpURLConnection post request fileNotFound

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have to make a `POST` request to an `ASP WEB APi 2 with OWIN login` which is expecting the following body:

```
grant_type=password
password=qwerty
username=administrator
```

However, I always get `FileNotFound` Exception with a `400` responseCode. I'm not really sure if I'm sending the `POST` data the correct way. Here is my code:

```
public JSONObject getLoginToken(String username, String password) {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        JSONObject response = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("someUrl");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("username", username);
            data.put("password", password);
            data.put("grant_type", "password");

            httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(data.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())); // <-- fails here

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            response = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is how the endpoint is created in `C#`, if it's of any help.

```
var client = new RestClient(Statics.API_LOCATION_URL + "login");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("username", "administrator");
request.AddParameter("password", "qwerty");
```

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not proper way. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post) you can find two useful answers how to do that properly (I'm recomending second one, not marked)

Comment: tried that already like this `String data = URLEncoder.encode("username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&grant_type=password", "UTF-8");`. Still got same error

Comment: nothing more I don't see... I would try to look for answer on server-side... also you wrote "...expecting the following **body**..." - you sure you have to send params in POST method? also you are using `setChunkedStreamingMode(0)` and from doc: "...Note, **not all** HTTP servers support this mode.". also: set some timeouts ;) all I can say about, good luck!

Comment: checking that server-side isn't "filtering" by headers or any other param I can't suggest anything... your code looks so simple and "perfect" ;) maybe you can check more about 400 error, [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)