# Why would this give me a 400 Error? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, http, http-status-code-400

I am trying to `PUT` a PHP array as a json.  This is what I have done:

```
$data = array('Customer Name' => 'White Carousel', 'Delivery Address'=>'2 Example Dr', 'Contact Phone Number'=>'555555555');
$json_data = json_encode($data);
```

When I try to `PUT` this, I am getting a 400 error.

Why is this?

I know what an Error 400 is, but I dont understand why it is coming here.  What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: straight duplicate of **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)** ... although typically you would POST to a server providing some kind of RESTful API.

Comment: What do you mean when I try to `PUT` this?

Comment: In the documentation of the API I'm communicating, it says that to update a record, I need to use a `PUT` request

Comment: When I say I am trying to `put` this json, I mean that I am trying to update a record on the API with this code.