# The request has an invalid header name. HTTP Error 400.

Tags: php, servlets, curl, http-headers, http-status-code-404

This is my curl request (found it on some old stackoverflow answer):

```
$headers[]  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0";
$headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
$headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
$headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
    
return $data;
```

And I get this error:

> Bad Request - Invalid Header
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

Do you have any ideea why I get this error and how should I fix it ?

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` for `User-Agent` (*my recommended way*)

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0');
```

**OR** (*not played with it*)

```
$headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0";
```

**instead of**

```
$headers[]  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another point to consider is whitespaces.

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
```

Wrong used

> "...Agent : Mozilla.."

This will send you

> Bad Request - Invalid Header
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.