# "no element found" error when using JSON stringify method in jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to update a section of a page using ajax when an image is clicked. When the image is clicked I pull values from a jQuery DataTable to populate an object. Then I call my action and pass in a JSON string of the object using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
$("#image").click(function(e) {

    data = {}

    table = $("#myTable").dataTable();
    $.each(table.fnGetData(), function(index, value) {
        row = $(table.fnSettings().aoData[index].nTr);
        data[row.find(".key")] = { 
            "val1": row.find(".val1").text(),
            "val2": row.find(".val2").text(),
            "val3": row.find(".val3").text(),
            "val4": row.find(".val4").text(),
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
       url: "myAction",
       contentType: "text/html",
       data: {
           json: JSON.stringify(data)
       },
       success: function(resp) { 
           alert(resp)
           $("#myDiv").html(resp);
       }
    });

});
```

However, calling the `ajax` function results in an error in the javascript console that only says "no element found". When I check the network activity it tries to hit the correct url, but returns a `400 error`.

I am sparing the back end details because I believe something in the `stringify` method to be the culprit here because when I pass a string literal as the ajax data such as `data: {json: "foo"}` it calls my action with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: are you sure that the url is /myAction ?

Comment: @MarcinC.yes, I am absolutely sure. When I pass a string literal as the json data it calls my action with no problem.

Comment: where exactly does that `element` error get thrown? Is `data` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Well, the 400 error is a back-end thing. If the browser console shows an HTTP request that you think looks OK, then you'll need to debug the server code.

Comment: The culprit is content-type, instead of text/html have it as application/json

Comment: @Pointy but it never calls my server code, I have a break point set on the first line of my action.

Comment: But you said that there's a 400 error.

Comment: that 400 comes from server not client

Comment: @rushi no, I don't think so - jQuery will turn the "data:" property value into a URL-encoded query string. *edit* though probably "text/html" is wrong; as Barmar says there's no need for "contentType" at all.

Comment: Leave out the `contentType:` option.

Comment: Leaving out the content type has the same effect. I suppose I will have to make double sure that no other code such as a filter is being called before it would get to my action code, I will report back

Comment: perhaps you are expecting a json payload...but that is not what will be sent the way you have it set up now

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, I am expecting html

Comment: I mean payload being sent to server, not the response

Comment: I just confirmed that it isn't hitting any type of filter code before my action, so the initial request must be getting denied by the server before anything I've created even happens. Again, I would like to emphasize that passing a string such as "foo" as the json data works just fine.

Comment: If you're getting a 400 error, that means that an HTTP request is being issued. Have you opened up the browser console to look at the request/response info?

Comment: Ok, so the rabbit hole gets deeper...the status code isn't even a 400 everytime...sometimes there isnt even a status code and the response type is "plain"....ugh, this is sad. @Pointy what data should I be looking at in the request/response info?

Comment: The request info will show the outgoing headers and the query parameters. The response will show the contents of the server response, as well as the response headers and status code.

Comment: Response headers:

Connection: close
Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2016 19:40:09 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Im definitely thinking malformed json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning but how could the JSON.stringify method silently create malformed json?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will not create malformed JSON. What's the `Content-Type` header in the response? What do your server logs say?

Comment: @Pointy Apparently xml? Firebug has an XML tab in the response section that says "XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{43263100-2b2a-479c-a38d-d6acac47a39d} Line Number 1, Column 1:
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8080/myAction"

Nothing even happens in my server logs, no activity from that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the ajax method as POST by adding the following attribute to the ajax call.

```
method: "POST"
```

No idea why this makes it work, but it does.