# HTML5 Geolocation timing out with a HTTP 400 using Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation, google-geolocation

When attemping to use HTML5 Geolocation method, I consistently get TIMEOUT errors when using Chrome.  I know similar questions have been asked, but all answers I've read direct the developer to use HTTPS & not a local env (ie: file:///).

I'm testing with the exact code sample from the  **Example** block at [Mozilla Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

I'm using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit).

I am using SSL / HTTPS (not self-signed, cert has valid cert auth).

I have confirmed the Location Service is allowed for the domain in question in Chrome Preferences.

I have successfully tested the same code using Safari.

I have tried with & without a valid Google API key with no difference.

I have enabled Google API Billing for the specific project that this API key is tied to in Google Dev Console.

Here's a screen shot of the error in console. [image: Error Msg in Chrome Console]

I don't know where else to look or what to try.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you answering "Yes" to the prompt from the browser asking you if you will share your location? Do you have a popup blocker installed? Have you   just tried pasting that example code into the `console` and running it from there. That worked without issue for me.

Comment: Yes to ^ and you also need to post your relevant code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I have said yes, previously, to the question regarding sharing my location & I'm seeing the GPS location indicator on the right hand side of my address bar.   Unfortunately, I am still seeing the error if I paste example directly into console.  I'm going to reset browser to default / factory settings & re-test.

Comment: @PhillipChan - Relevant code is in **Example** listed above.

Comment: 400 Error means this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning There must be some encoding going on in your Chrome.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I've reset to Chrome original defaults & error persists.  I'm going to read your suggested article now. Ty.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - If I reset Chrome to defaults (again), navigate to a generic page (IE: Google.com), and paste the example code directly into the console - I am greeted with the pop-up "Google would like to share your location...".      I click yes, then the same error pops up in the console as previous.  This test completely abstracts my source code from the issue.  :/

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or any kind of appliance that could be modifying the request?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - No, I'm not.  Currently working from home w/ a pretty standard env.  But I did figure something out.  I'm working in OSX 10.11.6.  I created a new user in my O.S.  Logged in as that user.  Opened Chrome & pasted example code into console, returning a successful result.  Changing the local user account resulted in the difference.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, you're past my pay grade on that one!

Comment: @ScottMarcus - That makes two of us!  I'm just going to re-create my local user account.  Not sure of the root cause here, but thank you very much for helping me narrow it down.