# gContact namespace not working

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am trying to POST contact data to GContact to create a new contact. I can create a new contact if I use only "gd" XML elements, but when I try and post a "gContact" element it gives me an error. I'm sure it's something simple because I am a total amateur, but I would appreciate any help.

This works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
    <gd:name>
        <gd:givenName>Jack</gd:givenName>
        <gd:familyName>Masters</gd:familyName>
        <gd:fullName>Jack Masters</gd:fullName>
        <gd:additionalName>Rascal</gd:additionalName>
        <gd:namePrefix>Sir</gd:namePrefix>
        <gd:nameSuffix>II</gd:nameSuffix>
    </gd:name>
    <atom:content type="text">These are some testing notes.</atom:content>
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" address="newtestAddress@gmail.com" primary="true" />
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">716-999-0098</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work">666-8765-9087</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">
        <gd:formattedAddress>3546 Madison Street, Chicago IL, 56879</gd:formattedAddress>
        <gd:street>3546 Madison Street</gd:street>
        <gd:city>Chicago</gd:city>
        <gd:state>IL</gd:state>
        <gd:country>USA</gd:country>
    </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
</atom:entry>
```

But this doesn't

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
    <gd:name>
        <gd:givenName>Jack</gd:givenName>
        <gd:familyName>Masters</gd:familyName>
        <gd:fullName>Jack Masters</gd:fullName>
        <gd:additionalName>Rascal</gd:additionalName>
        <gd:namePrefix>Sir</gd:namePrefix>
        <gd:nameSuffix>II</gd:nameSuffix>
    </gd:name>
    <atom:content type="text">These are some testing notes.</atom:content>
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" address="newtestAddress@gmail.com" primary="true" />
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="evenNewerAddress@yahoo.com" />
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">716-999-0098</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work">666-8765-9087</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">
        <gd:formattedAddress>3546 Madison Street, Chicago IL, 56879</gd:formattedAddress>
        <gd:street>3546 Madison Street</gd:street>
        <gd:city>Chicago</gd:city>
        <gd:state>IL</gd:state>
        <gd:country>USA</gd:country>
    </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
    <gContact:groupMembershipInfo href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/base/14b3e56788eb41b8" />
</atom:entry>
```

I have tried a number of different gContact elements and nothing seems to work. I get a 400 HTTP response code every time.

This is the response detail. I can't seem to figure where the error is.

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000234480> { URL: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Mar 2017 16:02:17 GMT";
    Expires = "Tue, 07 Mar 2017 16:02:17 GMT";
    Server = GSE;
    "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34\"";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block"; } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these recommended actions for error code 400 as given in [Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors):

- `invalidParameter`

  > Do not retry without fixing the problem. You need to provide a valid value for the parameter specified in the error response.
- `badRequest`

  > Do not retry without fixing the problem. You need to make changes to the API query in order for it to work.

You may want to also check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning) for additional insights that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was literally formatting every gContact element that I was trying incorrectly. I had tried 4 separate things and wrongly assumed it was something contextual I hadn't set. In reality I had formatted all four wrong in different ways. New programmer lesson learned.