# get http: 400 (Bad Request) ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cross-browser, ionic2

My ionic project was in **beta version** and now I updated to **latest version**.

when I do `ionic serve` i got this `error 404`.  I have removed my add block extension in chrome and searched in google for cross issue and i have installed the cross but it is not working.

> iframe_mx.html:8 GET http://pizdopletka.club?&&&ref=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2F&u…HTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F57.0.2987.98%20Mobile%20Safari%2F537.36 400 (Bad Request)
>
> affs?addonname=[ads]&clientuid=[Enter Client UID]&subID=mixsttest&affid=9652&subaffid=1003&href=htt…:2 GET http://static.cmptch.com/vablk.js?p=1&banner_id=23 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

i am not very well familiar about this question kindly help me I have no idea .

[image]

Comment: have you updated the ionic cli ?

Comment: @gerdi yes i did  i updated  my beta project to stable 2.2.0 after that only i am geting this err

Comment: @suraj are you familure with this error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning.. not sure

Comment: These look like spam urls to me. The *pizdopetka* one is listed as spam here: https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/apache-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker/blob/8203d585f9e22808b2e47fdb15c6d72c78252a05/custom.d/globalblacklist.conf