# Is this a Post request issue or an SSL verification issue

Tags: python, ssl, post, request

I'm trying to use a certain company's (not yet public) API.  In their documentation they lay out the format of the Token request.  Here's a copy of the documentation for a Token request:

```
POST
https://***.****.com/auth/realms/****/protocol/openid-connec
t/token
Headers:
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Basic {base64-encoded-key-and-secret}
Body: grant_type:client_credentials
```

The authorization key was given to me by them and is of the form `'Basic a3RhdmlfdG...'`
I'm trying to write a Post request in python and I'm having issues and I'm not sure if it's my fault or their developers fault.  Here's my code:

```
url = 'https://***.****.com/auth/realms/****/protocol/openid-connect/token'
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-urlencoded', 'Authorization':'Basic a3RhdmlfdG...'}
body = {'grant_type':'client_credentials'}
response = requests.post(url = url, data = json.dumps(body), headers = headers)
print response
```

At the line where `response = ...`I'm getting an `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error.  I've also tried changing the values in the headers to random values and I get the same error.  I can think of three possibilities, either

1. I'm making the Post request incorrectly
2. There is a problem with the API
3. I'm missing a certificate which I have to send with the Post request

   Is it one of these issues or is it something else?

Comment: #2 ... but you can tell requests to ignore_ssl_errors

Comment: The SSL error is gone thanks to SharpSol's suggestion, but now I'm getting a 400 error which should mean that it's some combo of 1 and 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably using a self signed cert.  You can bypass the verify check by adding 'verify=False'.  I would remove that before going to production.  It is important that SSL certs are valid.

```
response = requests.post(url = url, data = json.dumps(body), headers = headers, veryify=False)
```

Comment: "Bad Request", the API doesn't like something you are sending.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning