# jenkins Nexus Artifact Uploader 400

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm trying to upload my maven project to nexus after a success build on jenkins. Here are my both configurations:

Nexus
[image: Nexus]

And the jenkins configuration:
[image: Jenkins]

Here the error

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: 
Could not transfer artifact de.xxx:NettyCore:pom:1.0-20170508.212447-1 from/to cloud-repo (http://xxx:xxx/nexus/content/repositories/cloud-repo): 
Failed to transfer file: http://xxx:xxx/nexus/content/repositories/cloud-repo/de/xxx/NettyCore/1.0-SNAPSHOT/NettyCore-1.0-20170508.212447-1.pom. 
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.
ERROR: Uploading file pom.xml failed.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in "[400 BAD request HTTP error code meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19671511/6309)", an error 400 means the request was malformed.

In your case, a possible cause is the GAV you want to send: the Version is `1.0-SNAPSHOT`... sent to a *release* repo: that kind of version would be rejected by Nexus.
That "Repository policy" should be "snapshots" in order to accept `1.0-SNAPSHOT`.