# getting bad request instead of full error message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, superagent

I am trying to do error handling for `POST` with the same user email with the following(using `superagent`):

```
export function signUpUser(userData) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await request.post(`${url}/signup`).send(userData);
      set(window.localStorage, 'x-auth', currentUser);
      dispatch(signUpSuccessObject(userData));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(signUpFailObject(error));
    }
  };
}
```

I want to get the following which I can see in my network tab:

> {"name":"SequelizeUniqueConstraintError","errors":[{"message":"email
>   must be unique","type":"unique
>   violation","path":"email","value":"leo@fsl.co","origin":"DB","instance":

But instead all I get is:

> Bad Request

My controller for API:

```
User.create(
      Object.assign(req.body, {
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
      })
    )
      .then(() => {
        const myToken = jwt.sign({email: req.body.email}, 'leogoesger');
        res.status(200).send(myToken);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
  },
```

Comment: Status 400 (aka "Bad request") indicates a client error (such as malformed syntax, size too large, etc.). This is not really the source of your error, in particular in case of a DB field that fails validation. Have you tried sending back a different status code to see if that's what's blocking you from seeing the error client-side? My guess is, the browser's default behavior might take over on some specific status codes, and 400 might be one of them?

Comment: Apparently, the choice of what status code to use for a situation like yours is up for debate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning - some very interesting answers & comments there.

Comment: The problem is `error` in dispatch. What I should have used is `error.response`. It is weird how it works different from `onSuccess` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send()` will send plain `text/html` responses.

Use `res.json(myToken)` and `res.status(400).json(err)` for a JSON API.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1074

^^ Used this as a reference.

Basically, I need `error.response`. This will give me the entire object, which will allow me to get access to the error message.

So full working code would be:

```
export function signUpUser(userData) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await request
        .post(`${url}/signup`)
        .send(userData)
        .type('json');
      set(window.localStorage, 'x-auth', currentUser);
      dispatch(signUpSuccessObject(userData));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(signUpFailObject(e.response.body));
    }
  };
}
```