# java HttpURLConnection throwing a response code: 400 for URL for large requests

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send a request over a URLConnection using `HttpUrlConnection`, which is working but the `response code: 400` is being thrown when getting the response back with `connection.getInputStream()`. The web Service I am writing to is sending large JSON response. In fact when I try small requests ( therefore small responses) the program works fine. Its a matter of size of response being too large.

```
URL obj = new URL(url);



    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //building the json request.. tested and works fine
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestParameters);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes(json);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); //Program throws exception here for large response
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    connection.disconnect();
```

how can i improve my code in a way that it can be able to read large response from web service?

Comment: Are you sure it is because large response? I  googled 400 response code,it is said bad request.So I guess your large request may have some syntax errors(it is not a valid json),you can output it and test if it is a valid json.See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)

Comment: I wil try that however the exception is being thrown on connection.getInputStream() not before when I request to the server

Comment: @ChaojunZhong i just validated the json and it is valid. thereis no problem with my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.
If the server is returning 400 it means that **it** can't handle large requests, so the main fix has to be done in the server code.

If you want to make a shorter json we could help you if you show us that requestParameters, maybe we can figure out a way to split that json into shorter requests.

It would be useful too to see your e.stackPrintTrace(), or the connection.getErrorStream().

Comment: This answer helped me thanks. It was an issue from the server side.