# How can I make a Put rest call along with POJO using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

**How can I make a PUT request to a rest service using RestTemplate, so that I get a response also.**

The rest service I have to call is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = /forgotpassword, method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
public SuccessResponse resetUserPassword(@RequestBody ResetPasswordDTO resetPasswordDTO) throws GenericException {
    logger.info("--->reset Password");
    return new SuccessResponse(userservice.resetUserPassword(resetPasswordDTO));

}
```

I need to send one POJO also which has two String properties.

Comment: Do you have any view methods to show? This is just controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `PUT` use `RestTemplate.exchange()` method

**Example**

```
 MyJaxbRequestDataObjectrequest = createMyJaxbRequestDataObject();
    Map<String, String> uriArguments= createUriArguments();
    String url = restBaseUrl + "/myputservice/{usertId}?servicekey={servicekey}";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpEntity<MyJaxbRequestDataObject> entity = new HttpEntity<MyJaxbRequestDataObject>(request, headers);
    ResponseEntity<MyJaxbResponseDataObject> responseWrapper = shogunRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, MyJaxbResponseDataObject.class, uriArguments);
    MyJaxbResponseDataObjectresponse = responseWrapper.getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method put of `RestTempalte` in (Spring)[https://spring.io/] has no return,so if your want get response from server,please try use `POST` method.I modify your code like this:

In server side:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/forgotpassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse> resetUserPassword(@RequestBody ResetPasswordDTO resetPasswordDTO) throws Exception {
        log.info("--->reset Password");
        SuccessResponse response = new SuccessResponse();
        response.setName(resetPasswordDTO.getUsername());
        response.setMessage("success");
        return new ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

In client side you can use RestTemplate do a request:

```
ResetPasswordDTO request = new ResetPasswordDTO();
        request.setPasswork("Huawei@123");
        request.setUsername("c00382802");
        ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse> response =template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080//forgotpassword",request,SuccessResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());
```

More info you can get from (Spring)[https://spring.io/]

Comment: Server side code is already running, we cannot change it. From client it is mandatory to use only PUT request.