# 400 bad request : can't figure out the request problem

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I have to read a file in a OneDrive sheet using prestashop.
I can't use the microsoft/microsoft-graph packet with composer because it need guzzle v6 and prestashop is locked at v5 so i'm rigting the request myself but it seems i'm missing something.

I got the credential figured out, I have my access token (without it or a random string gives me an 401 error).

Now I'm trying to read a file, but even easier than that, I can't list the recent files in my drive.
I can do it on the graph explorer (beeing connected) and do whatever I want but whtin the code I always get an "400 error Bad request" with no other detail.

Here is my code, if you can point me to te right direction?

```php
        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent';
        $req = $guzzle->get($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2',
                'Accept'     => 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            ],
            'body' => [
            ],
        ]);
```

EDIT :

The problem seems to be about authorisation, here is the code :

```php
<?php
// 1/ retrieve the access token

        $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
        $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
            'body' => [
                'client_id' => $clientId,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
                'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                //should I use this
                'roles'=>[
                    "Sites.Read.All",
                    "Files.Read.All"
                ],
                //or this?
                'scp' => 'Sites.Read.All Files.Read.All'
            ],
        ])->getBody()->getContents());
        $access_token = $token->access_token;

// 2/ read file content
        $userId = 'email@domain.fr';
        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . $userId . '/drive/items/##FILE_ID##/workbook/worksheets(\'Export\')/range(address=\'a2:d4\')?$select=values';
        //$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . $userId . '/drive/list';

        $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $req = $guzzle->get($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            ]

        ]);
// this return a 403 forbidden
        $ret = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: **Related:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning - You're probably calling it wrong or passing the wrong data to it.

Comment: @Script47 Yes I know that, the thing is I can't find out what is wrong or missing... First time using microsoft graph.

Comment: Try to leave out the `body` part completely here.

Comment: @misorude Unfortunatly I tried that already, the error is still the same.

Comment: Try sending only the Authorization header.

Comment: @misorude I just tried your solution but it didn't work. On the graph explorer I can see the detailed request in the browser console "XHR request" and even with that I can't see what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you acquire access token (application permission token) via [Client credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow, in that case there is **no** `Me` context since it represents *signed-in user context* (applicable for [delegated permission token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) only).

For *application permission token* user needs to be explicitly specified, for example:

To call [`List recent files` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) at least `Files.Read.All` and `Sites.Read.All` permission levels are required.

[image]

Once permissions are *granted*  and *consented* as illustrated below

[image]

`roles` claim should contain the following list of permissions:

```
"roles": [
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Files.Read.All"
  ]
```

[image]

```
$userId = "<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . $userId . '/drive/recent';
$guzzle = new Client();
$headers = ['Authorization'=>'Bearer ' . $accessToken];
$response = $guzzle->get($url,['headers' => $headers]);
$json = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
```

---

To determine whether access token is delegated or application permission,  [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) service, for instance, could be utilized:

for *application permission token*, the permissions are provided in the `roles` claim:

[image]

For *delegated permission token*, the permissions are specified via `scp` claim instead

[image]

**How to get access token**

```
function getAccessToken($tenantId, $clientId, $clientSecret){
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
    return $token->access_token;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, i'll try that (I need and admin to grant access).

Comment: I got aprooval from the admin but I can't get access, I have a 403 forbiden now, I call it progress!

Comment: I don't understand the access configuration.
First, I get the token using grant_type = client_credentials.
Then I call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@email.com/drive/items/###DOC_ID###/workbook/worksheets and I get 403 forbidden.
If I understand @vadim correctly I need to change the credential request? Or first I get the acesstoken and then call a request to grant me access for this token?

Comment: @RomainLeMercier, the answer has been updated (demonstrates what permissions are required and how to validate access token)

Comment: Sorry to ping you but you seems to know your stuff and I really don't, the more I google or read the doc, the more I'm lost...

Comment: @RomainLeMercier, just spotted in your example `body` parameter is utilized to perform post request , in GuzzleHttp (v 5.0 or above)  `form_params` request option needs to be utilized instead(the updated answer contains an example on how to acquire access token)

Comment: Yes I use Guzzle V5 and in the version the param needs to be "body", form_params came with V6 (and I can't update due to prestashop dependencies). In your exemple to get the access token I don't see any roles ou scp param to get permition. Is it not in this request I have to ask for it? Or is it an other request?
Right now I have only two :
1/ get accen token
2/ get file content (where I have a 403 error).

Comment: @RomainLeMercier what file content?  In your question, there is a mention about `me/drive/recent` endpoint only Can you be more specific and provide all the relevant details in your question, the way how you communicate at the moment make it difficult to assist you IMHO