# Failed API Call - How to handle "Error 400" for Jurassic API?

Tags: python, transformer-model, jurassic

When setting up the API call for Jurassic (requested from https://studio.ai21.com/docs/api/), I always get the 400 error response.

```py
import json
import requests

   requests.post(
    "https://api.ai21.com/studio/v1/j1-large/complete",
    headers={"Authorization": "PERSONAL API KEY"}, 
    json={
        "prompt": "Life is like", 
        "numResults": 1, 
        "maxTokens": 8, 
        "stopSequences": ["."],
        "topKReturn": 0,
        "temperature": 0.0
    }
)
```

Output: <Response [400]>

Could anyone give me some advice please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [400 BAD request HTTP error code meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are wrong, as the documentation indicates that the API key should be preceded by `Bearer` . Try this:

```
import json
import requests

YOUR_API_KEY = 12345678 #define API key here

requests.post(
    "https://api.ai21.com/studio/v1/j1-large/complete",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {YOUR_API_KEY}"},
    json={
        "prompt": "Life is like", 
        "numResults": 1, 
        "maxTokens": 8, 
        "stopSequences": ["."],
        "topKReturn": 0,
        "temperature": 0.0
    }
)
```