# How to manage PyCharm error 400 with git clone (GitHub)

Tags: git, github, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have an issue with PyCharm Pro and cloning the git (GitHub) repository. The problem is on 2 computers, all with Windows 10 Pro.

I can add a GitHub account in PyCharm. The account is found and I can see all of my repo. When I do a git clone, PyCharm asks how to log in to GitHub (choice of log in via GitHub or Use Token). But my account is already connected in PyCharm... If I select one of the 2 options and give right informations (again), I have a message :

> "Clone failed unable to access 'https://github.com/.../repo.git/': The
> requested URL returned error: 400 show details in console"

when I see the details in console, I have this :

> "15:22:18.748: [pythonProject] git -c credential.helper= -c
> core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false init Initialized empty
> Git repository in .../pythonProject/.git/

If I clone my repo with the console, I have no problem. Only happens under PyCharm. I tried with account log or token, the problem is still the same.

I tried a different version of PyCharm, but the problem is still the same. I do not understand what is wrong...

Comment: It appears it's network issue. Error 400 is usually  "A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules."  Try check if the URL has any errors. Not related to pycharm, but you'll get an idea of what 400 error is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The URL is right, and if i do a git clone with a command (outside pycharm), all is okay. I do not understand why i have a problem with pycharm...

Comment: Okay. See if the method of connecting is same? SSH vs HTTPS? Which one you're using outside PyCharm? Which one you're using inside PyCharm?

Comment: This is the same, by HTTPS for both

Comment: You're saying URL is right. But the error saying URL might be an issue. If I were you, I would take hard look at how it's "perceiving" the URL. Can you try pycharm in linux, if possible?