# Vue.js POST 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, mongoose, fetch-api

My frontend service is like below, I want to send a JSON body to my node.js server backend. The console.log(sample) is shown in console with  correct format and with correct data that I want to send, and so is console.log(requestOptions). However, my node backend side keep on return POST 400(Bad Request). Can anyone help me with the code?

**Vue**
service.js

```
import config from 'config';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';

export const sampleService = {
    addNewSample,
}
function addNewSample(sample){
    console.log(sample);
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: authHeader(),
        body: JSON.stringify(sample)
    };
    console.log(requestOptions);
    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/samples/newAdd`, requestOptions);
}
```

---

**Node.js**
controller.js

```
const express =require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const sampleService = require('./sample.service');

//routes
router.post('/newAdd', addSample);
//router.get('/:id', getById);

module.exports = router

function addSample(req, res, next){
    console.log(req);
    sampleService.create(req.body)
    .then(() => res.json({}))
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

service.js

```
const config = require('config.json');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const db = require('_helpers/db');
const Sample = db.Sample;

module.exports = {
    create
};

async function create(sampleParam) {

    console.log(sampleParam);
    const sample = new Sample(sampleParam);

    // save sample
    await sample.save();
}
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning) but I don't know how to revised my code to make my backend to return 200 success.

Comment: What is `authHeader()`? Does it correctly set the content-type header? If not, there's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `authHeader()` only returns an object with the `Authorization` key, you are missing the required `Content-Type` header to identify the request body as JSON

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    ...authHeader(),
    "content-type": "application/json", //  added header
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(sample),
};
```

On the server-side, you also need to ensure you have the correct middleware for handling JSON request bodies

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: After I add "content-type": "application/json" to my headers, the backend server finally return 200. Thanks!