# How to receive formdata from axios in asp.net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

In my react app project I am sending a formdata post by axios to a local web api service on .net core 6. The formData has a file and a folder name appended properties but the request to the service returns :
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
[1]     at settle (file:///D:/Documents/React/psarchetypeeditor/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (file:///D:/Documents/React/psarchetypeeditor/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
[1]     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
[1]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
[1]   code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
this is my post code :

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('folder', folder);
  formData.append('file', file);
  
  console.log("formData")
await axios.post('https://localhost:7275/Upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false,}),
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log("Response Data :       " + response.data);
    res.json(response.data);
  }).catch ((error) => {
    console.error('Upload proxy error:    ', error);
    return res.status(500).send('Upload proxy error');  
  })
})
```

What would be the problem and how should exactly be the service to get this type of information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [400 BAD request HTTP error code meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning)

Comment: could you show the controller of your webapi?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was that while I receive the file data in the proxy server by express fileupload middleware I need to change the file.data to Blob and then I can send it by axios as formdata to the api service and it works.