# Linkedin API access token generation error

Tags: linkedin-api

i am trying to generate access token to collect linkedin data. I followed the instructions provided in the linkedin API documentaion. I created an app in developers page and got the following:

```
Application Details
•   Company:
Fresher
•   Application Name:
xxxxxxxxxx
•   API Key:
75pcum6zb2cael
•   Secret Key:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
•   OAuth User Token:
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
•   OAuth User Secret:
xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
```

Using the **API Key** i generated the **authorization_code** with the URL:

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75pcum6zb2cael&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com

but when i finally tried to generate the access token using the below URL, i got an error response :

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&client_id=75pcum6zb2cael&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> {"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid
>   parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access
>   token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or
>   authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}

Even after multilple validations, the same error messages appears.

please help. thanks.

Comment: Not a programming question, but an issue with a vendor's API.

Comment: Can explain in detail, what was the bug? could you please post your answer, so that would be helpful

Answer (score 31, accepted):

finally, i got the access token. The authorization code expires in 20 seconds, so the access token URL must be called immediately after generating the authorization code.

Comment: I am getting accessToken but not getting secretToken value!! Any idea.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Unable to get the access token. Even before I can get 'code' from params it throws an exception.

Comment: In my case, code is generating at front-end side (angular), and I've set redirect_uri=http://192.168.1.133:9004/v1.0/jobSeeker/getSocialMediaUser AS a redirect url; But I'm getting Below error..When trying to generate access_token Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists

Comment: Can anyone tell me What is going wrong with my code?

Comment: @KetavChotaliya , how did you resolved your error? can you post your answer here please

Comment: @PrasannaSasne As mention in answer, a token will expire in 20 sec.
We have to use LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 for the authentication
> Create an app in LinkedIn and generate secret keys
> Do authenticate the user via LinkedIn (Generally in the frontend). It will return security token. that is valid till next 20 sec.
> Generate AccessToken from security token (Generally from Backend), Here u've to mention security token, hostname, secret token and other stuff
A hostname is must equal to frontend hostname (from where security token generate)
> Now u've an access_token, Get the details from token

Comment: @KetavChotaliya i'm following linkedin Doc only, i'm able to retrieve Auth token, but when i pass my authtoken code, client_secret, client_id etc params, like @Rick has made the call for access Token, still i'm unable to get that token, i've posted my question newly, can you try answering that please? ,` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501144/unable-to-get-access-token-linkedin-oauth`

Comment: But LinkedIn says "... the authorization code has a 30-minute lifespan ..." ???  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

Answer (score 15):

Well, I went through the same problem and here is the process which i went through to fix it.

**STEP#1: Authentication**:

1. Firstly, the authentication API is to be hit to fetch the authentication token.
2. For this, a URL with **Encoded** parameters is to be hit as a **GET** request.
3. Example: `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=[your_client_id]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&scope=r_emailaddress`
4. Please note that here, the parameters are to be encoded programatically.
5. My non-encoded callback URL is: http://localhost:8080/linkedin/callback
6. Therefore, my encoded URL is: http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback

Once you hit this as a GET request, you will receive a callback with a `code` and an optional `state` parameter.

**STEP#2: Getting Access Token:**

There are three pre-requisites to this call:

1. The call must be `POST`
2. It must have a header `Content-Type` with value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. The data must be sent in request body.
4. The value of `redirect_url` **MUST BE SAME** as in the previous call.
5. In my case, it was: http://localhost:8080/linkedin/callback

Now the trick here is, that the call in (STEP#1 Authentication) was a GET request. Therefore, the `redirect_url` had to be programatically encoded.

Since the second call for is `POST` and is also `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded, therefore the request body parameters do not have to be explicitly encoded. So, in this case, the `redirect_uri` would be sent as-is (http://localhost:8080/linkedin/callback)

Here is a snapshot of my Access Token API via postman:
[image]

Comment: The snapshot and the details about "encoded" or "non-encoded" URL solved my problems

Answer (score 6):

My problem was in `redirect_uri` which contained url with query parameters (like `redirect_uri=encodeURIComponent(http://example.com/callback?query=string)`).

If redirect url is completely different linkedin will show you an error before showing you login form, but if redirect_url matches what you specified in linkedin app **and** contains extra query parameters, you'll not get an error, so once login form is submitted you'll get an invalid code and as a result error as above.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be **scopes** related.

On the details of your application when selecting scopes there is this message:

[image]

> Selecting both r_basicprofile and r_fullprofile is redundant.
>   r_basicprofile will be selected if neither r_basicprofile nor
>   r_fullprofile is checked.

If you are selecting both **r_basicprofile** and **r_fullprofile** just uncheck **r_basicprofile** or remove it from your [Authorization Code Request](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2).

Comment: can you please help me, as i'm facing same problem. I tried many ways. sharing my question link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501144/unable-to-get-access-token-linkedin-oauth`

Comment: Are these permissions still valid? I only see r_emailaddress` and r_liteprofile and everything else seems to have been removed by linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case I was using different `redirect_uri` for authorization and for access token. I had `"proxy": "localhost:3001"` in my `package.json`, and it overriden my `request_uri`.

So my suggestion: make sure the hosts and `redirect_uri` are all the same for two requests (both backend and server side).