# Unable to get access Token linkedin Oauth

Tags: sapui5, linkedin-api

I know some will put comment like this post is duplicate of so many questions, but I've tried many ways to achieve Access Token in linkedin Oauth. Explaining what i tried.

1) I'm following it's official doc's [Linkedin Oauth2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2-legacy#ux)

2) I'm successfully getting Authorization code from step 2 and passing that code to step 3 for exchanging Auth code for getting Access Token. But i'm getting following error
*{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}*

3) According to some links i need to set content-type in the header.[Link which tells to set content-type is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585655/missing-required-parameters-includes-an-invalid-parameter-value-parameter-more)

4)Then i tried calling `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken` this service instead of `POSt` to `GET`. And passing data as queryParams.

5) Some [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027589/linkedin-oauth2-request-token-400-bad-request) says oauth code expires in 20 sec, So i've checked, i'm making call for access token in less that 1 sec.

6) And if i pass data in Body params like as below and used url as `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken`

```
var postData = {
                grant_type: "authorization_code",
                code: authCode,
                redirect_uri: 'https%3A%2F%2Foauthtest-mydeployed-app-url',
                client_id: 'my_client_id',
                client_secret: 'secret_key'
            };
```

7) With `Get` call my url i tried 
`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code='+authCode+'&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauthtest-mydeployed-app-url&client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=secret_key`

Still i'm getting Error even though status code is 200, i'm getting that error(with `GET` api)
and If `POSt` by passing `postData` in body i'm getting bad request `400` status code

Not understanding why m I not getting access code. I've read many solutions.
Sharing code as requested.

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
 "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function (Controller, MessageToast) {
 "use strict";

 return Controller.extend("OauthTest.OauthTest.controller.View1", {
  onPress: function (evt) {
   var sPath =
    'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauthtest-mydeployed-app-url&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&scope=r_basicprofile';
   window.location.href = sPath;
            var oRouter = new sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
   oRouter.navTo("View2", {
    "username": "Test"
   });
   MessageToast.show(evt.getSource().getId() + " Pressed");
  },
  
  //after user allows access, user will be redirected to this app with code and state in URL
  //i'm fetching code from URL in below method(call is happening in max.569ms)
  
  onAfterRendering: function () {
   var currentUrl = window.location.href;
   var url = new URL(currentUrl);
   var authCode = url.searchParams.get("code");
   if (authCode !== undefined && authCode !== null) {
    var postData = {
     grant_type: "authorization_code",
     code: authCode,
     redirect_uri: 'https%3A%2F%2Foauthtest-mydeployed-app-url',
     client_id: 'my_client_id',
     client_secret: 'secret_key'
    };
    
   /* var accessTokenUrl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + authCode +'&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauthtest-mydeployed-app-url&client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=secret_key';*/

    var accessTokenUrl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken';

    $.ajax({
     url: accessTokenUrl,
     type: "POST",
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     },
     data: postData,
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
      alert('success');
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
      alert('error');
     }
    });
   }
  }

 });
});
```

Help will be appriciated..!!!

Comment: as mention in error, you have to check below things
1) Make sure access code is not expired.
2) URL for generate access token will be: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
3) Method: POST
4) POSTFIELDS are as below 
i) grant_type='authorization_code'
ii) code="<ur access code>"
iii) redirect_uri=<exacttly same URL were access code is generated>
iv) client_id=<LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID>
v) client_secret=<LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET>

Comment: Below is sample code (in PHP) for your reference.

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$code."&redirect_uri=".env('LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URL')."&client_id=".env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID')."&client_secret=".env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

Comment: @KetavChotaliya, i tried with post according to your 1st comment, in that case i'm getting bad request and status code as 400. and we need to pass `content-type` in the header too. and i checked my access code is not getting expired though

Comment: Need to debug carefully...flow is same as I mentioned above. If possible share your code.

Comment: @KetavChotaliya added code for more clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I am happy to post my answer after so much search.
Every step I did is correct only, but one thing I was missing here like, Linkedin API doesn't supports CORS.

I tried implementing Javascript SDK, that works like charm. But API wasn't. 
Then I found very helpful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512646/cors-blocks-linkedin-share-api) which says I need to implement Rest API from backend by allowing CORS, not from front end.

Make sure to follow all the points which I mentioned above in my post.
And for [Allow CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check) follow this link. You will get data but only basic profile of user according to LinkedIn Terms [data can be accessible](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Hope this post may help someones time to search more

Comment: first thing I was going to say was that javascript call to the api would probably fail due to browser protections on CORS yap.
anyway, my issue on my side was just a time problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094926/linkedin-oauth2-unable-to-verify-access-token/28220525?noredirect=1#comment79610296_28220525